# How to load my app from Eclipse to my Android phone instead of AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, android-virtual-device

I'm quite new to Android and have been using an AVD to debug my app so far. However, I want to start checking the media options and therfore need to start using my Android phone. How do I get Eclipse to load my app to my phone instead of my AVD?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

First you need to enable USB debugging on your phone, then connect it to your computer via USB. Then eclipse should automatically start debugging on your phone instead of the AVD.

Comment: Eclipse will choose the device (or virtual device) that most closely matches the API version of your project, unless you're in manual mode.  If your phone is 2.1 (API 7 I think) and you have a 1.6 AVD (API 4), I've seen eclipse start the AVD even when the phone is plugged in if your project is set for 1.6.  The last time I tried this was a while ago though, I'm not sure if this is still the case.

Comment: 1. From the home screen, press the Menu button below the screen.

2. Tap the Settings option.

3. Choose Applications.

4. Select Development.

5. Check the box for USB Debugging to turn it on.

Comment: While the answer is valid, it is not always this simple. Your OS might not detect the phone as mentioned by Yahel in another answer. Go through the android guide on debugging to avoid frustration. You can also use the command 'adb devices' to check if your phone has been recognized - http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: @Asimov4, check out my answer below, it seems like USB Debugging is hidden in some of the newer devices and versions, so your answer may no longer be valid..even though it helped me get to my solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Choosing "Manual" in Run Configuration worked.

Comment: But how to on java-eclipse screen?

Answer (score 23):

just for additional info,
If your apps is automatically run on emulator,
right click on the project, Run As -> Run Configuration,
then on the Run Configuration choose on the Manual.
after that, if you run your apps you will be prompted to chose where  you want to run your apps, there will be listed all the available device and emulator.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, and have not been able to get Eclipse in Windows 7 to recognise the device. The device is correctly configured, Windows 7 recognises it on the USB port, and I edited the Run settings in Eclipse to prompt for a device, and it is just not there.

I ran it with the following steps:

- Connect the device to the computer with USB.
- Ensure the device is not locked (ie. timed out in the UI). I have to keep unlocking it while I'm working.
- Wait for Windows to recognise the USB device, and when the autoplay menu comes up select `Open device to view files`. It should open up the file system in the device, in Explorer.
- In Explorer go to the Eclipse workspace and find the `apk` file from the build (eg. `MyFirstApp.apk`)
- Copy the apk file to the Downloads directory on the device
- On the device, use the `My Files` app (or similar) to open the Downloads directory.
- Click the downloaded file (`My First App.apk`) and Android offers to install it
- Select `install`
- The app is now in the installed Apps. Run it.

A second method is to mail the apk file to the device and then download and install it. (Credits to a post on SO which I can't find now).

A third method is to use DropBox. This requires installation of DropBox on the PC and on the device (from the play store) but once both are set up it runs very smoothly. Just share a DropBox folder between the two devices, and then drop the APK into that folder on the PC, and open it on the device. With this method you don't need a USB connection, and can also install the APK on multiple devices. It also assists the management of multiple development versions (by making a separate sub-folder for each version).

Comment: I was also facing the same problem. This solved my problem. Thanks !!

Comment: i don't see a fix in this. eclipse should run the application on device directly, not to scratch over the head (don't know if in english is correct) and copy files.

Comment: @mihai71: You are right this does not fix the problem, but works as a workaround To run the app on the Android-device.

Comment: NOTE TO READERS: This solution for loading apps from Eclipse gets the occassional upvote (as of July 2018). I quite like the boost to my reputation, but it also indicates to me that the problems with Eclipse in Windows remain. I have been using AndroidStudio (free, and based on IntelliJ) for two years now and it haven't looked back. It beats Eclipse in every way for Android development, and is recommended and supported by google, and also the Android community. The installation time and learning curve are moderately significent (not just a day), but well worth it.

Comment: Google ends support for Eclipse tools for Android. https://www.androidpolice.com/2016/11/02/google-officially-ends-support-for-eclipse-android-developer-tools-in-favor-of-android-studio/. AndroidStudio download. https://developer.android.com/studio/

Answer (score 9):

In Eclipse:

- goto run menu -> run configuration.
- right click on android application on the right side and click new.
- fill the corresponding details like project name under the android tab.
- then under the target tab.
- select 'launch on all compatible devices and then select active devices from the drop down list'.
- save the configuration and run it by either clicking run on the 'run' button on the bottom right side of the window or close the window and run again

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do anything really except prepare your phone to be able to run debug and usb apps :

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

then simply launch your app from eclipse and your device will be used if you don't have a simulator running.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Enable USB debugging on your device.

On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.

On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.

In eclipse go to Run Configuration and select **Always prompt to pick device**[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some people may have the issue where your phone might not immediately get recognized by the computer as an emulator, especially if you're given the option to choose why your phone is connected to the computer on your phone. These options are:

- charge only
- Media device (MTP)
- Camera file transfer (PTP)
- Share mobile network
- Install driver

Of these options, choose MTP and follow the instructions found in the quotes of other answers.

- Hope this helps!

> goto run menu -> run configuration.
>   right click on android application on the right side and click new.
>   fill the corresponding details like project name under the android tab.
>   then under the target tab.
>   select 'launch on all compatible devices and then select active devices from the drop down list'.
>   save the configuration and run it by either clicking run on the 'run' button on the bottom right side of the window or close the window and run again

Answer (score 3):

For those who are trying to find how to enable debugging on devices running Jelly Bean 4.2 (e.g Google Nexus), you have to go to **Settings > Apps > About tablet and tap the text "Build number" 7 times** slowly.  Go back to the now available **Settings > Developer options** and check USB debugging as stated in previous posts.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the Andriod Device is installed on PC. See steps below. The 'Other device' will change to 'Andriod Device' once the USB drive is installed. The browse path should be 
\extras\google\usb_driver\
not the sub directories under it. Otherwise the installation will not find the package.

To install the Android USB driver on Windows 7 for the first time:

Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
Select Devices in the left pane.
Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.
Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
Click Next to install the driver.

Answer (score 2):

connect your device to system and set you device debug mode on when you run your application Android Virtual Device AVD will select device there you will see your connected device select your mobile device and thats all refer this link to set your device debugging mode on

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html
[image: device manager showing your device]

Answer (score 1):

The USB drivers in \extras\google\usb_driver didn't work for me.

However the official drivers from Samsung did:
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Note: I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.0 on Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

What I did, by reading all of above answers and it worked as well: 7 deadly steps

1. **Connect** your **android phone** with the pc on which you are running **eclipse/your map project.**
2. Let it install all the necessary **drivers.**. When done, open your smart phone, go to: **Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging** and enable it on by clicking on the check button at the right side.
3. Also, enable **Settings > Unknowresoures**
4. Come back to **eclipse** on your pc. Right click on the project/application, **Run As > Run configurations... >Choose Device>Target Select your device Run.**
5. Click on the **Target** tab from top. By default it is on the first tab **Android**
6. Choose the second radio button which says **Launch on all compatible deivces/AVDs**. Then click **Apply** at the bottom and afterwards, click **Run**.
7. Here you go, it will automatically install your application's **.apk** file into your smart phone and make it run over it., just like on emulator.

**If you get it running, please help others too.**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks this helped.  It was a little tricky getting the USB debugging option enabled on the Samsung G3 after the update.

See below
[Instructions on Samsung G3 Jellybean](http://www.technipages.com/android-developer-options-is-missing.html)

1. Settings
2. Click --> About the phone
3. Tap on the build number
4. “You are now 4 steps away from being a developer.” Keep tapping until it says “You are now a developer.”
5. Go back to Setting-->System --> Developer option: Enable USB Debugging

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

1. Connect your phone to computer via USB
2. Enable USB debugging on your phone: *Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging*
3. Change Run configuration in your Eclipse project:
   *right click -> Run As -> Run Configurations*. In the *Target* tab choose *Always prompt to pick device* (or *Manual*). Then *Apply, Run*.

In the new window you should see your connected phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can Debug Android Application While you are developing them follow these steps..
Make sure that you have *PC suite* of the mobile manufacturer. For Example:if you are using samsung you should have *samsung kies*

1.Enable USB debugging on your device:**Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging**
2.Enable Unknownresources:**Settings>Unknowresoures**
3.Connect your device to PC
4.Select your Application Right click it: **RunAS>Run configurations>Choose Device>Target** Select your device **Run**.

You can also without using debugging cable.For that you need to install [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) in your device.After installing enter the link in your browser and Drag and Drop .apk file.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set your device to debugging mode. On Android 4.X that means as described in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707217/25282) in another question:

> Open up your device’s “Settings”. This can be done by pressing the Menu button while on your home screen and tapping “System settings”
>
> Now scroll to the bottom and tap “About phone” or “About tablet”.
>
> At the “About” screen, scroll to the bottom and tap on “Build number” seven times. *[Note this is no joke]*
>
> Make sure you tap seven times. If you see a “Not need, you are already a developer!” message pop up, then you know you have done it correctly.
>
> Done! By tapping on “Build number” seven times, you have unlocked USB debugging mode on Android 4.2 and higher. You can now enable/disable it whenever you desire by going to “Settings” -> “Developer Options” -> “Debugging” ->” USB debugging”.

The next step is to connect your device to your computer via the USB cable.

The next step is to install a USB driver for it. On the [official website](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) you find a list with sources for drivers for phones from various different companies.

Eclipse now should give you the phone as a choice when you click on Run and it presents you possible device to launch.

In some case Eclpise will tell you Target Unknown which prevents you from using the device. If that's the case you might have to restart the phone. You might also have to check and recheckUSB debugging, till the phone asks you to allow your particular computer to do usb debugging.