# How to run app on Android Device using Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing my first app for Android, for now I was using ADT for running app, now I want to run app on Android Device, how can I do so, help needed.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please follow the below link . [Run On Real Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load my app from Eclipse to my Android phone instead of AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992357/how-to-load-my-app-from-eclipse-to-my-android-phone-instead-of-avd)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just Connect your Device , and Make Sure you have enabled USB debugging in your Device Settings and also installed the appropriate drivers in your Machine. you can download the device driver file from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html and also have look here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: To see the option for USB debugging mode in Android 4.2 or higher, do the following:

    Open up your device’s “Settings”. This can be done by pressing the Menu button while on your home screen and tapping “System settings”
    Now scroll to the bottom and tap “About phone” or “About tablet”.
    At the “About” screen, scroll to the bottom and tap on “Build number” seven times.
        Make sure you tap seven times. If you see a “You are now a developer!” message pop up, then you know you have done it correctly. (from http://bit.ly/1gyxopb)

Comment: When you have done the 7 taps, press your phone's back button and you will see the new "Developer options" menu item. Go into there and you will see the option to enable "USB debugging". You should then see your device in Eclipse. :)

Answer (score 9):

1. Install the [ADT plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)
2. Install phone drivers (if needed)
3. Plug the phone into the computer
4. In Eclipse, *"Run → Run as → Android application"*

Answer (score 3):

For those who are trying to find how to enable debugging on some of the newer devices running Jelly Bean 4.2 (e.g Google Nexus), you have to go to **Settings > Apps > About tablet and tap the text "Build number" 7 times** slowly.  Go back to the now available **Settings > Developer options** and check USB debugging.