# Android debugging on Thrive

Tags: android, debugging, tablet

Is there anything special that needs to be done for Eclipse to see my Thrive for some USB debugging?  I have debugging enabled on the tablet.  Eclipse doesn't seem to see it.

Thanks

Comment: Refer my answer in this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649261/how-to-run-app-on-android-device-using-eclipse/6649315#6649315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install USB driver using AVD on Windows. Details can be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html which also includes how to set it up for Linux/Ubuntu.

Normally, the device driver will install itself automatically when you connect it the first time.  I found I had to modify the driver INF file when I did it for MyTouch 4G since it's not in the list.  You can simply open the INF and add something like the following as long as you know the device VID and PID,

```
;NVIDIA Tegra
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_7100
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_7100&MI_01
```

I found the above ( http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/enable-adb-usb-drivers-for-nvidia-tegra-based-android-tablets/) by googling Thrive, so it should work on Windows.  The INF file can be found at the location where you installed the SDK, e.g. c:\android-sdk-windows\usb_driver\android_wiinusb.inf.