# Eclipse - Errors 'Android Package Builder'

Tags: android, eclipse, package, builder

I have a problem with running app on Android Virtual Device in Eclipse. When I try to run my project this error appears:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'AddingNumbers'.
sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
```

The log file is this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 566 2018-08-24 18:38:43.274
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 75 2018-08-24 18:38:43.275
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'AddingNumbers'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalPackage(BuildHelper.java:391)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalDebugPackage(BuildHelper.java:359)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

I tried to install Java 8 instead of Java 10 and selecting jre1.8.0_181 from Window-->Preferences-->Java-->Installed jres

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: why are you still using eclipse/ADT ! It's support has been officially terminated in favor of Android Studio by Google.

Comment: Android Studio does not work properly on my low end PC. I have 4 GB Ram and 2.0 GHZ Processor. When I try to run a project with Android Studio it is very very very slow.

Comment: ok, does your project run fine on physical device ?

Comment: I did not try. How can I do? I enabled Debug USB on my device but after i do not know how to run it on device with Eclipse.

Comment: just plug in your device, eclipse will list your physical device in device chooser while running project. See more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992357/how-to-load-my-app-from-eclipse-to-my-android-phone-instead-of-avd

Comment: it does install the app on my device but when i try to run it, it closes instantanely. How can i fix this?

Comment: it's crashing, see logcat for error trace

Comment: you mean the .log file into Eclipse-workspace -->metadata directory?

Comment: no, see this to view/enable logcat https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280126/3141231

Comment: yes but it does not show anything

Comment: try running again your app on device, something useful should be printed on logcat

Comment: Failed to load properties file for project "..."

Answer (score -1):

Edit the `eclipse.ini` file with below options for `-vmargs`,

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
```